# jquery ajax modal problem firing validate and submithandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Think i'm lost in my code... can't figure out the problem. I have a modal that opens different forms, setting name and id on the form and submit button accordingly, but nothing happens when pressing submit button. My javascript knowledge is limited and based on try and fail and try and fail and try and sometimes achieving results :)

Back to the issue here... The modal opens fine but nothing happens when hitting submit... Nothing visible to me at least...

Hope i have explained my problems ok.

This calls the modal

```
<span class="stedModal" data-type="sted" title="Legg til sted" style="cursor: pointer"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
```

The modal:

```
    <!-- Modal - Legg til sted -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Legg til sted</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<!-- name and id is set to sendStedForm in the script that calls the modal -->
                <form action="javascript: void(0)" name="none" id="none" class="modalForm">
                    <div class="main"></div>
<!-- addSted.php is inserted here -->
                    <div class="text-end"> 
<!-- button name and id is set by the script that calls the modal to submitSted -->
                        <button type="submit" name="none1" id="none1" class="btn btn-sm btn-info submitButton" ><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Lagre</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Lukk</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

calls addSted.php

```
 <input type="hidden" name="lag_id" id="slag_id" value="<?= session()->get('lag_id'); ?>">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sted">Sted<span class="text-danger fw-bold">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="sted" id="ssted" class="form-control required" placeholder="Sted">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="oppmote">Oppmøte<span class="text-danger fw-bold">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="oppmote" id="soppmote" class="form-control" placeholder="Oppmøtested">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sted">Oppmøte tid<span class="text-danger fw-bold">*</span><small class="text-muted">Timer før oppdrag starter</small></label>
                    <input type="text" name="oppmote_tid" id="soppmote_tid" class="form-control" placeholder="Oppmøte tid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The scripts

```
<script>

function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}

$('#alert').hide();

$('.stedModal').click(function() {
    var typet = $(this).data('type');

    if (typet == 'type') {
        var url = '/vakter/ajaxAddType';
        $('.modalForm').attr('id', 'sendTypeForm');
        $('.modalForm').attr('name', 'sendTypeForm');
        $('.submitButton').attr('id', 'submitType');
        $('.submitButton').attr('name', 'submitType');
        $('.modal-title').html('Legg til Type');


    } else if (typet == 'sted') {
        var url = '/vakter/ajaxAddSted';
        $('.modalForm').attr('id', 'sendStedForm');
        $('.modalForm').attr('name', 'sendStedForm');
        $('.submitButton').attr('id', 'submitSted');
        $('.submitButton').attr('name', 'submitSted');
        $('.modal-title').html('Legg til Sted');
    }

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){ 
            // Add response in Modal body
            $('#alert').hide();

            $('.main').html(response);
            
            // Display Modal
            $('#Modal').modal('show'); 
        }
    });
});


if ($("#sendStedForm").length > 0) {

    $("#sendStedForm").validate({
        rules: {
            sted: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 100,
            },
            oppmote: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 100,
            }, 
            oppmote_tid: {
                pattern: /^[0-9,]+$/,
                maxlength: 4,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            sted: {
                required: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Legg inn sted</small>",
                maxlength: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Sted bør ikke være så langt. 100 tegn er maks</small>",
            },
            oppmote: {
                required: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Legg inn en kort beskrivelse</small>",
                maxlength: "Beskrivelsen bær ikke være så lang. Maks 100 tegn</small>",
            },  
            oppmote_tid:  {
                pattern: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Skriv inn ett gyldig nr</small>",
                maxlength: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Oppmøte tid er for langt. Maks 3 tegn</small>",
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('hi');
            $('#submitSted').html('lagrer..');
            // var lag_id = $("#slag_id").val();  
            // var sted = $("#ssted").val();  
            // var oppmote = $("#soppmote").val();  
            // var oppmote_tid = $("#soppmote_tid").val(); 
            // if (!oppmote_tid) { oppmote_tid = '0';}
            // oppmote_tid = oppmote_tid.replace(/,/g, '.');
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('/vakter/ajaxAddSted/post') ?>",
                type: "POST",
                // data: $('#ajax_form').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                // data: { lag_id : lag_id, sted : sted, oppmote : oppmote, oppmote_tid : oppmote_tid },
                data: $('#sendStedForm').serialize(),
                success: function( response ) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(response.success);
                    $('#submitSted').html('Submit');
                    $('#alert').html(response.msg);
                    $('#alert').addClass(response.typemsg);
                    $('#alert').show();
                    // $('#res_message').removeClass('d-none');
                    // document.getElementById("ajax_form").reset(); 
                    // alert("User record updated successfully with ID: "+response.id);  
                    $("#sted").append('<option value="'+ response.id +'">'+ sted + ' - ' + oppmote + ' - ' + oppmote_tid + ' timer</option>')
                    $('#stedModal').modal('hide'); 
                    
                    $('#submitSted').html('<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Lagre');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#alert').hide();
                        $('#alert').html('');
                    },10000);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There's alot going on there. For troubleshooting, use the web inspector that comes with your browser. In the `console` area you'll see any errors that might be happneing, in the `network` area, click on `xhr` and there you'll see all the ajax requests, what they're sending and what you're getting back. Once you open the web inspector and go to `network` refresh your page for it to start working

Comment: Nothing happens in Network/xhr when clicking submit button. I had this working earlier, but only with one modal. Tried to backtrace it to this, and startet to do it step by step. And is seems to me that jquery won't recognize the form or submitbutton when id and name has been set by jquery itself using `$('.modalForm').attr('id', 'sendStedForm');`. I might need to look for another solutions running several forms in one modal. @Kinglish

Comment: Hi, your code i.e : `$("#sendStedForm").validate({.` is on page load . So , when you initialize your form that form doesn't exist inside your dom because on click of your span you are changing form ids..etc . That's why nothing happens when you click on submit button . Instead move that code inside *success* function of ajax and try again.

Comment: Thank you @swati. Sounds very logical :) went for another solutions with multiple modals. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the sendStedForm inside a function and call it after the dom actually has the sendStedForm id to work with which is after ajax data is loaded and placed inside html. Although I have not tested this, but I hope this should work.

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}

$('#alert').hide();

$('.stedModal').click(function() {
    var typet = $(this).data('type');

    if (typet == 'type') {
        var url = '/vakter/ajaxAddType';
        $('.modalForm').attr('id', 'sendTypeForm');
        $('.modalForm').attr('name', 'sendTypeForm');
        $('.submitButton').attr('id', 'submitType');
        $('.submitButton').attr('name', 'submitType');
        $('.modal-title').html('Legg til Type');


    } else if (typet == 'sted') {
        var url = '/vakter/ajaxAddSted';
        $('.modalForm').attr('id', 'sendStedForm');
        $('.modalForm').attr('name', 'sendStedForm');
        $('.submitButton').attr('id', 'submitSted');
        $('.submitButton').attr('name', 'submitSted');
        $('.modal-title').html('Legg til Sted');
    }

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
            // Add response in Modal body
            $('#alert').hide();

            $('.main').html(response);

            // Display Modal
            $('#Modal').modal('show');

            process_sendStedForm();
        }
    });
});


function process_sendStedForm(){
    if ($("#sendStedForm").length > 0) {

        $("#sendStedForm").validate({
            rules: {
                sted: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 100,
                },
                oppmote: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 100,
                },
                oppmote_tid: {
                    pattern: /^[0-9,]+$/,
                    maxlength: 4,
                }
            },
            messages: {
                sted: {
                    required: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Legg inn sted</small>",
                    maxlength: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Sted bør ikke være så langt. 100 tegn er maks</small>",
                },
                oppmote: {
                    required: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Legg inn en kort beskrivelse</small>",
                    maxlength: "Beskrivelsen bær ikke være så lang. Maks 100 tegn</small>",
                },
                oppmote_tid:  {
                    pattern: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Skriv inn ett gyldig nr</small>",
                    maxlength: "<small class=\"text-danger\">Oppmøte tid er for langt. Maks 3 tegn</small>",
                },
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                alert('hi');
                $('#submitSted').html('lagrer..');
                // var lag_id = $("#slag_id").val();
                // var sted = $("#ssted").val();
                // var oppmote = $("#soppmote").val();
                // var oppmote_tid = $("#soppmote_tid").val();
                // if (!oppmote_tid) { oppmote_tid = '0';}
                // oppmote_tid = oppmote_tid.replace(/,/g, '.');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('/vakter/ajaxAddSted/post') ?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    // data: $('#ajax_form').serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    // data: { lag_id : lag_id, sted : sted, oppmote : oppmote, oppmote_tid : oppmote_tid },
                    data: $('#sendStedForm').serialize(),
                    success: function( response ) {
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log(response.success);
                        $('#submitSted').html('Submit');
                        $('#alert').html(response.msg);
                        $('#alert').addClass(response.typemsg);
                        $('#alert').show();
                        // $('#res_message').removeClass('d-none');
                        // document.getElementById("ajax_form").reset();
                        // alert("User record updated successfully with ID: "+response.id);
                        $("#sted").append('<option value="'+ response.id +'">'+ sted + ' - ' + oppmote + ' - ' + oppmote_tid + ' timer</option>')
                        $('#stedModal').modal('hide');

                        $('#submitSted').html('<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Lagre');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#alert').hide();
                            $('#alert').html('');
                        },10000);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems logical. Will remember this next time :)
Went for multiple modals this time.. But It will be used later :) @ympervej